# Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, tar

```
burakkaymaz4444@penguin:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Hit:3 https://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Ign:4 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/105 bullseye InRelease
Hit:5 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/105 bullseye Release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
57 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
burakkaymaz4444@penguin:~$ sudo apt install python3 python3-pip build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev default-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.9).
default-jdk is already the newest version (2:1.11-72).
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.3-6).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1n-0+deb11u3).
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.3.4-4+deb11u1).
python3 is already the newest version (3.9.2-3).
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.9.2-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
burakkaymaz4444@penguin:~$ tar -xf pycharm-community-2022.2.tar.gz
tar: pycharm-community-2022.2.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
burakkaymaz4444@penguin:~$
```

I want to download Pycharm but I see this error what can I do to fix it (linux Debian os chromebook)?

I use this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sykiO1A7J1g&t=220s)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nobody really wants to spend minutes to watch a video: you have to explain what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: you need to actually download pycharm and also change to the directory where you saved it (so probably the Downloads folder). also search for jetbrains toolbox, that will help you

Comment: 1) After you have updated your system (`sudo apt update` __`&& sudo apt upgrade`__, with only the 1s part you update only the list of dependencies, not really the system), you need to 2) __Download__ the file (`pycharm-community-2022.2.tar.gz`, but it can have a different number too) 
3) move the file to the present directory (`mv ~/Download/pycharm-community-2022.2.tar.gz .`) -- Note you may want to create in advance a directory for this (mkdir MyPyFolder) and go into (cd MyPyFolder) and only then `mv ~/Download/pycharm-community-2022.2.tar.gz .` ) --
4) Finally you can open it with `tar`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to download PyCharm before running the tar -xf command:

```bash
wget https://download-cdn.jetbrains.com/python/pycharm-community-2022.2.tar.gz

tar -xf pycharm-community-2022.2.tar.gz
```